# .htaccess: how to redirect folder to to .php file?

Tags: .htaccess

Is there a way to create a redirect like the one below?

```
/abcd/ => /abcd.php
```

I'm trying this, but it's not working:

```
Redirect 301 /abcd/ /abcd.php
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

---

```
RewriteRule ^abcd/?$ /abcd.php [L,R=301]
```

---